# 3 Count functions returning the same value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, count

So i have this query:

```
SELECT Posts.[Post ID], Count(Comments.[Comment ID]) AS [CountOfComment ID],
Count(Shares.[Share ID]) AS [CountOfShare ID],
Count(Likes.[Like ID]) AS [CountOfLike ID]

FROM ((Posts INNER JOIN Likes ON Posts.[Post ID] = Likes.[Post ID]) 
INNER JOIN Shares ON Posts.[Post ID] = Shares.[Post ID]) 
INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.[Post ID] = Comments.[Post ID]

WHERE posts.[post id] = 5 

GROUP BY Posts.[Post ID];
```

Which should return the results:

```
post.[post id]= 5 
CountofcommentID= 4
CountofShareID = 5
CountofLikeID = 15
```

But instead i get `post.[post id] = 5, and the rest =300.`

I know that this is because it is counting up all the permutations of all the IDs, but how do i change that to get the results that i want?

Comment: ms access  or mysql????

Comment: The syntax is clearly MS Access, so I adjusted the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `COUNT()` does.  It counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  The proper solution is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  Because MS-Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT)` you might interpret that as "get a functional database".

Inside MS Access, you can do this using subqueries of some type.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT p.[Post ID],
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Post Id], [Comment ID]
              FROM Comments as c
             ) as c
        WHERE c.[Post Id] = p.[Post Id]
       ) as [CountOfComment ID],
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Post Id], [Share ID]
              FROM Shares as s
             ) as s
        WHERE s.[Post Id] = p.[Post Id]
       ) as [CountOfShare ID],
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Post Id], [Like ID]
              FROM Likes as l
             ) as l
        WHERE l.[Post Id] = p.[Post Id]
       ) as [CountOfLikes ID]
FROM Posts as p
WHERE p.[post id] = 5 
GROUP BY p.[Post ID];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you join, you get a row for every combination. Therefore, count does count every row, which has value different from null. So, what you want is to count DISTINCT ids. I.e.:

```
SELECT Posts.[Post ID], Count(DISTINCT Comments.[Comment ID]) AS [CountOfComment ID],
Count(DISTINCT Shares.[Share ID]) AS [CountOfShare ID],
Count(DISTINCT Likes.[Like ID]) AS [CountOfLike ID]

FROM ((Posts INNER JOIN Likes ON Posts.[Post ID] = Likes.[Post ID]) 
INNER JOIN Shares ON Posts.[Post ID] = Shares.[Post ID]) 
INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.[Post ID] = Comments.[Post ID]

WHERE posts.[post id] = 5 

GROUP BY Posts.[Post ID];
```

If the system does not support this syntax, you might need to do subqueries:

```
Select Posts.[Post ID], 
   (Select count([Share ID]) from Shares where Posts.[Post ID] = Shares.[Post ID]) as SharesCount
FROM Posts

WHERE posts.[post id] = 5;
```